# Twitter-typeahead shows no results even if the query returns results

Tags: laravel, eloquent, twitter-typeahead

After some research, I couldn't fix my problem. I'm using twitter-typeahead, and it's not showing results, but when I check the response in the network, it shows me the results. What could be the reason my typeahead doesn't show results even if there is a result in the query.

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control typeahead" type="text" name="variant"
                                    placeholder="Search by BRNO,variant ..." />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var Variants = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/sales/br-number/search?query=%QUERY%',
            wildcard: '%QUERY%',
            cache: false,
        },
    });

    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        source: Variants,
        display: function(data) {
            return data.br_no+' '+data.variants_name.toUpperCase()+' '+data.case_bottles.quantities;
        },
        templates: {
            empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
                'No Results',
            '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function(data) {
                return '<p><strong>' + data.br_no + '</strong> '+ data.variants_name +' <strong>' + data.case_bottles.quantities + '</strong> </p>';
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Controller**

```php
public function br_number_search(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request['query'];

    return $variants = Variant::with('case_bottles', 'product')
        ->where('br_no', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
        ->get();
}
```

Response Screenshot:

[image]

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Hmm, what do you get when you dump $query after assigning it?

Comment: Actually when i looked at the network response its working.. I mean the results are coming but for some reason the typeahead just shows no results no matter what

Comment: Can you post an api response you are getting?

Comment: i have upload the reponse's screenshot

Comment: Did you check the console if a javascript error occurs?

Comment: No errors in console :D. If there was one at least i could go in search of that error. But in my case no errors anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If the network is returning something, it may be as simple as you are not returning the data in the format the view needs.  IE if this were returning part of a view, you would want to send the whole stream as a Laravel view:

```
$variants = Variant::with('case_bottles', 'product')
    ->where('br_no', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
    ->get();

return view('something', compact('variants'));
```

Since this is going back through an async pull, I think you probably just need to stringify it or json_encode the data so it transmits properly.  Perhaps after getting `$variants`, something like:

```
return json_encode($variants));
```

Then just remember to decode inside your typeahead function if necessary.

Comment: I will try this method

Answer (score -1):

Counting your comment

> Actually when i looked at the network response its working

this question doesn't fits the tags 'laravel' and 'eloquent'.
It's much closer to tag 'javascript' and of course tag 'jquery' as **typeahead.js is jQuery plugin**.

Your query

`return $variants = Variant::with('case_bottles', 'product')
        ->where('br_no', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
        ->get();`

returns collection object, but the JS code

`display: function(data) {
            return data.br_no+' '+data.variants_name.toUpperCase()+' '+data.case_bottles.quantities;
        }`

looks like not ready for mentioned data type.

So, please read carefully 2 advices by @watercayman and use them together

1)
`return json_encode($variants));`

2)

> remember to decode (json data) inside your typeahead function

Comment: The network response is perfectly fine. With an ajax call the response is returned as json from Laravel. Also the display function is fine and matches the response. I use it exactly the same way.